# Finding the limit of $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\tan2x}{\sqrt{3x+1}-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, trigonometry

Finding this limit pretty hard because $\tan$ has fewer formulas (mentioned in my school book) unlike the other trigonometric functions like $\sin$ or $\cos$.

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\tan2x}{\sqrt{3x+1}-1}$$

I tried to solve it using factoring and I reached a level where I'm stuck at this

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\tan2x  \left(\sqrt{3x+1}+1\right)}{3x}$$

I'm not quite sure if the progress is correct or not in the first place so help please to solve this.

Comment: See here for the trigonometric addition formulae: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricAdditionFormulas.html

Comment: Do you know L'Hospital rule ?

Comment: Unfortunately, i'm not good at math

Comment: @momoshki There is a mathematical spelling problem in your limit expression, see : $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\tan2x  {\color{red}{(}}\sqrt{3x+1}+1{\color{red}{)}}}{3x}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\tan2x  \left(\sqrt{3x+1}+1\right)}{3x}$$

Then, observe that:

$$\begin{align}\frac {\sin 2x}{\cos 2x}\cdot \frac {1}{3x}&=\frac 23\cdot\frac {\sin 2x}{2x}\cdot \frac {1}{\cos 2x}\end{align}$$

Comment: is there any more clearifcation please

Comment: @momoshki Of course, with pleasure. Note that, $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {\sin 2x}{2x}=1$$ Does this help ?

Comment: You can also solve it by seing that tan(2x) ~ 2x at 0 then you take the limit because the x of the fraction cancel out and you get 4/3

Comment: So the answer should be 4/3 ?

Comment: @momoshki Exactly.